# How to make backgrounds for 3D games?

Tags: 3d, skybox

I've started to study game design and I couldn't really find an answer for this one. Let's imagine a small level with a nice (non passable) background in the distance. The background has mountains, hills, town and a forest. The background, should it be a part of the skybox? or 2D sprites? or low poly models? What's the best approach?

(...and sorry for the bad english, long day and I'm really tired...)

Comment: There's no good answer to this -- it depends on what kind of game you are making, what kind of look you want it to have, what kind of technology you're using, and a whole host of other factors. There's unfortunately no "best" option here. If you could narrow down the kind of project _you_ are working on, we may be able to provide guidance. If you're just looking for sort of a discussion and survey of available techniques, you might find some success over at [GDNet](http://www.gamedev.net).

Comment: That's your answer to everything Josh.  :-p I joke.  But GDNet, and their discord in particular, is an amazing resource.

Comment: I mean games like an arena shooter for example. Rayman M/Arena had some beatiful backgrounds. But they look more like a part of the skybox? 

It's at 4:05
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e0rL5pmbPXw

Comment: @RaoulL'artiste On the video that you linked (for Rayman) it doesn't look like they are using skyboxes at all, it's literally just a texture plane on the edge of the map. When making a game, you can use this technique, or a skybox, or anything else you can imagine. As they say, the sky is the limit.

Comment: @RaoulL'artiste With a background/sky in a game, the main thing is trying to minimize performance cost while maximizing look.  If a background isn't going to have to move with respect to the camera, you can use a flat plane.  Otherwise, if you don't need to see any parallax (objects moving at different speeds based on distance), you can just bake them into the skybox, yes.  Again, the only reason not to use a skybox is if you're seeing warping, or you want the background to be interact-able or moving in some way.

Comment: @RaoulL'artiste Also, in the video you provided, it looks like they might have some more custom geometry that roughly follows the shape of the level, because it seems too close to be a skybox, and not exactly cubical in shape., though it's essentially the same thing: textured geometry at the edge of the world with the background painted on it.